# Can someone walk me through this line of code?

Tags: python, pandas

```
for col in cols_with_missing:
    imputed_X_train_plus[col + '_was_missing'] = imputed_X_train_plus[col].isnull()
    imputed_X_test_plus[col + '_was_missing'] = imputed_X_test_plus[col].isnull()
```

what does

> imputed_X_train_plus[col + '_was_missing']

mean?

Comment: You forgot to add a pandas tag. You really don't need to understand this code if you're just starting.

Comment: But the code creates a new column in the dataframe whose name is based on another column.

Comment: What is `imputed_X_train_plus`? Python's objects behave differently depends on their type. [mcve] please.

Comment: The contents of the new column is a NaN mask off the existing column it is based on.

Comment: Thanks.I am reading introduction to ML on kaggle.So trying to understand it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll fabricate some data for illustration. Consider

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

imputed_X_train_plus = pd.DataFrame({'joe': [3, np.nan],
                                     'nick': [np.nan, 6],
                                     'fred': [1, 7]})
```

At this moment, `imputed_X_train_plus` is a data frame with NaN values.

```
      joe   nick  fred
   0  3.0   NaN   1
   1  NaN   6.0   7
```

Suppose you somehow have known which columns have missing values. They are in `cols_with_missing`.

```
cols_with_missing = ['joe', 'nick']
```

Now you want to mark out those missing values. So you do

```
for col in cols_with_missing:
    imputed_X_train_plus[col +'_was_missing'] = imputed_X_train_plus[col].isnull()
```

Now you are having `imputed_X_train_plus` like

```
   joe  nick  fred  joe_was_missing  nick_was_missing
0  3.0   NaN     1            False              True
1  NaN   6.0     7             True             False
```

To conclude, `col + '_was_missing'` made a new `str` (like `joe_was_missing`) which is used to insert a new column name for `imputed_X_train_plus`.